# Как реализовать нажатия клавиш в четко указанное время, находящееся в массиве в c#?

Tags: c#, sleep, .net-4.8

У меня есть массив, содержащий в себе время в миллисекундах. timeMs = {200, 32, 23, 77, 23..., 87}
Каким образом можно реализовать нажатия клавиш четко во время, указанное в массиве? Реализовывал через Thread.Sleep(timeMs[i]), либо Task.Delay(timeMs[i]).Wait(). Результат - накапливается задержка. Через время программа имитирует нажатия не тогда, когда мне нужно.
Каким образом можно реализовать так, как я описал?
Пример кода:

```
        public void Start()
        {
            IntPtr AdofaiWindow = FindWindow(null, "A Dance of Fire and Ice");
            if (SetForegroundWindow(AdofaiWindow))
            {
                Task.Delay(500).Wait();
                SendKeys.SendWait("e");
                TimeInMsList[0] = 1900;
                Thread.Sleep(TimeInMsList[0]);
                for (int i = 1; i < TimeInMsList.Length; i++)
                {
                    SendKeys.SendWait("e");
                    Thread.Sleep(TimeInMsList[i]);
                }
                SendKeys.SendWait("e");
            }
        }
```

В голове была идея реализовать отнимание 40 от TimeInMsList[i] при приостановке потока, а это помогало, если время больше 100ms, но тогда проблема с случаями, когда время меньше 40ms. Почему 40? Это примерное время приостановки и возобновления потока, если я не заблуждаюсь.

На мое удивление, при асинхронной задержке не происходит абсолютно ничего. Оказалось, что выводится только 'start'.

```
        public async void Start()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Start");
            IntPtr AdofaiWindow = FindWindow(null, "A Dance of Fire and Ice");
            if (SetForegroundWindow(AdofaiWindow))
            {
                await Task.Delay(500);
                TimeInMsList[0] = 1900;
                for (int i = 0; i < TimeInMsList.Length; i++)
                {
                    //SendKeys.SendWait("e");
                    await Task.Delay(TimeInMsList[i]);
                    Console.WriteLine("Release key");
                }
                SendKeys.SendWait("e");
            }
            Console.WriteLine("End");
        }
```

Не понимаю, почему происходит подобное из-за плохого понимания того, как все происходит на деле.
Чуть переписал код. Спасибо aepot.

Метод main. Следовательно, и вызов метода, реализующего нажатия.

```
static void Main()
        {
            string path = @"D:\all levels\32 Akiba(13)\backup2.adofai";
            LevelParser newLevel = new LevelParser(path);
            
            int[] time = MathFloor.GetListTimeMS(newLevel);
            /*foreach (var item in time)
            {
                Console.Write(item + " ");
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
            newLevel.PrintLvlInfo();*/

            ReleaseKey rk = new ReleaseKey(time);
            rk.Method();
        }
```

LevelParser - реализует извлечение данных из файла.
В итоге массив time содержит время в ms.

Как я реализовал класс реализации нажатий?

```
        private int[] TimeInMsList;
        public ReleaseKey(int[] timeInMsList)
        {
            TimeInMsList = timeInMsList;
        } //конструктор
        private async Task StartAsync()
        {
            IntPtr AdofaiWindow = FindWindow(null, "A Dance of Fire and Ice");
            if (SetForegroundWindow(AdofaiWindow))
            {
                await Task.Delay(500);
                TimeInMsList[0] = 1900;
                for (int i = 0; i < TimeInMsList.Length; i++)
                {
                    SendKeys.SendWait("e");
                    await Task.Delay(TimeInMsList[i]);
                }
                SendKeys.SendWait("e");
            }
        } //метод, реализующий нажатия
        public async void Method()
        {
            try
            {
                await StartAsync();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
            }
        } //с помощью этого метода я могу вызывать StartAsync() в методе main()
```

Приложение консольное. SendKeys.SendWait() позволяет реализовывать глобальные нажатия. Реализовываю переход между окнами с помощью `IntPtr AdofaiWindow = FindWindow(null, "A Dance of Fire and Ice"); if (SetForegroundWindow(AdofaiWindow)) {`
Итог выполнения программы - её завершение при первом await Task.Delay().

Answer (score 1):

Разобрался. Спасибо aepot! Итог:

```
public async Task StartAsync()
{
    IntPtr AdofaiWindow = FindWindow(null, "A Dance of Fire and Ice");
    if (SetForegroundWindow(AdofaiWindow))
    {
        await Task.Delay(500);
        TimeInMsList[0] = 2350;
        SendKeys.SendWait("e");
        await Task.Delay(TimeInMsList[0]);

        for (int i = 1; i < TimeInMsList.Length; i++)
        {
            SendKeys.SendWait("e");
            await Task.Delay(TimeInMsList[i] - 40);
        }
        SendKeys.SendWait("e");
    }
}
```

метод `Main()`:

```
static async Task Main()
{
    string path = @"D:\all levels\32 Akiba(13)\backup2.adofai";
    LevelParser newLevel = new LevelParser(path);
        
    int[] time = MathFloor.GetListTimeMS(newLevel);
    /*foreach (var item in time)
    {
        Console.Write(item + " ");
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
    newLevel.PrintLvlInfo();*/
    ReleaseKey rk = new ReleaseKey(time);
    await rk.StartAsync();
}
```

Моя невнимательность является следствием того, что я сразу не понял, что программа отрабатывает так, как нужно.

Comment: Ну `- 40` может и не помочь. Задержка не имеет стабильного значения. Можно похитрее с секундомером сделать.

Comment: абсолютно правы. я склоняюсь к тому, что нужно реализовать с помощью таймера, но все мои попытки его реализовать, пока, приводят до того, что он работает не так, как нужно.